# TSQL: generate random string in Update statement

Tags: sql-server

I need to obfuscate a SQL Server database by changing all text values by the random string with equal length:

```
qwert -> vno3w
a123456 -> vn58wof
```

I can't use procedure or function in `UPDATE`, and some of string can have thousands of symbols, so `GUID` isn't a variant.

The best that I have found is something like

```
declare @BinaryData varbinary(max)
, @CharacterData varchar(max)
, @Length int = 2048

set @BinaryData=crypt_gen_random (@Length) 

set @CharacterData=cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@BinaryData"))', 'varchar(max)')
```

The reason is to check new components performence on DB like production (client don't give us backup without removing real user data like that).
Foreign keys isn't problem in my current case.

Could you help, please?

Comment: 1.  This is *way* too broad.  2.  Why on Earth would you ever need to do something like this?

Comment: Show us what you already have.

Comment: You can encrypt the whole database.

Comment: What about values that are currently foreign keys? You can't update one with the other unless you disable the foreign key. And then you have to make sure you update both sides to the same random value. There are just too many what ifs here.

Comment: What is wrong with what you already have?  Looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '' + symbols FROM (
SELECT CHAR(
CASE WHEN r between 0 and 9 THEN 48
WHEN r between 10 and 35 THEN 55
ELSE 61 END + r) symbols
FROM
master..spt_values
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT CAST(RAND(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) *61 as int) r) a WHERE type = 'P' AND number < 3333) symbols
FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS RandText
```